# ClassNotFoundException in sbt project

Tags: java, scala, sbt, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

For the life of me [my scala build tool project](https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/scalatype) is just riddled with ClassNotFoundExceptions.

All I have to do is clone it and do `sbt run` and I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/Utils$$anonfun$1
        at com.example.Utils$.shortenTypeSignature(Utils.scala:10)
        at com.example.Hello$.getTypedDeclaration$1(Hello.scala:69)
        at com.example.Hello$.iterateThroughSourceFile$1(Hello.scala:113)
        at com.example.Hello$.main(Hello.scala:157)
        at com.example.Hello.main(Hello.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.Utils$$anonfun$1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at com.example.Utils$.shortenTypeSignature(Utils.scala:10)
        at com.example.Hello$.getTypedDeclaration$1(Hello.scala:69)
        at com.example.Hello$.iterateThroughSourceFile$1(Hello.scala:113)
```

Previously, I had to insert a variable of type `GlobFinder` in [Hello.scala](https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/scalatype/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/example/Hello.scala) or else I would get:

```
/*
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: info/collaboration_station/utilities/GlobFinder
  at info.collaboration_station.utilities.FileFinder.tryFindAbsolutePathOfFileWhoseNameIs(FileFinder.java:128)
  at com.example.Hello$.main(Hello.scala:137)
  at com.example.Hello.main(Hello.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: info.collaboration_station.utilities.GlobFinder
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 3 more
 */
```

Fix was to add this line...

```
val vvv = new GlobFinder("foo")
```

Why is [my Scala project](https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/scalatype) so rife with ClassNotFoundExceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. The project is running `clean` on itself. It must be deleting its own class files.

That being said, removing `clean` from

`val proc = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(Array[String]("sbt", "clean", "set scalacOptions in ThisBuild ++= Seq(\"-print\")", "compile", "exit"))`

^ in Hello.scala didn't fix anything.